# how to write $f'$?

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{2009}(x+k)-c$

$f'(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{2009}(x+k)\sum_{k=0}^{2009}\frac 1{x+k}$ $\forall x\notin\{-2009,-2008,...,0\}$

Is this representation of $f'$ correct? cause clearly here $f'$ is not continuous, meanwhile $f'$ is polynomial so it has to be continuous

Comment: In your calculus textbook, look for "logarithmic differentiation".  The discontinuities are removable.  It is true that $\frac{1}{x+k}$ has a problem at $x=-k$, but it is multiplied by $(x+k)$ in the first part, so that problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Your computation of the derivative is correct for $x \in A = \mathbb R \setminus \{-2009,-2008,...,0\}$... And $f^\prime$ is continuous on $A$ even if $\sum_{k=0}^{2009}\frac 1{x+k}$ is not on $\mathbb R$.

The problem is that your derivative is not defined on $\{-2009,-2008,...,0\}$ but can be if your write

$$f^\prime(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2009}\prod_{l=0, l \neq k}^{2009}(x+l)$$

Comment: So in the exam, I should write f' the way you have written not the way I have written right? or will I get away with my style of writing f'?

Comment: Your way of writing has some flaws. As I wrote while $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$, your way of writing only provides a derivative on a subset of where it should. In my answer, $f^\prime$ is defined on $\mathbb R$. All will depend on the attention and flexibility of the grader!